# How to add attachments to docx using python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to use Python to add attachments to docx, and I am using python-docx. But I couldn't achieve it

I have read the document of python-docx and found that there is no interface for inserting attachments implemented. I have checked that python-pptx has an interface for inserting attachments, and now I want to know how to combine the implementation in pptx with docx. What should I do?
Or, have other ways to add attachments to docx？ Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.